# How to var_dump?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I've been searching the internet for hours but I just can't seem to var_dump within the invoice template. I need to put things like EAN etc. in the invoice template but only for certain customer groups, that's why I need to know the variable names.

In Shopware 5 it was `var_dump` plain and easy but in Shopware 6 nothing I try seems to work.

I've already tried `{{ dump() }}` within twig code blocks but nothing happens.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.shopware.com/en/en/shopware-6-en/tutorials-and-faq/debugging)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general `{{ dump() }}` should work inside document templates, but the `dump` command is optimized for html output and not pdf output.

Please ensure that you set `APP_ENV = "dev"` or `APP_DEBUG = 1` inside your .env file, because otherwise the twig `dump()` command is not available.

Also ensure that you call the `dump` from a block that is rendered in the output of the document (so everything inside the `<body>` tag).

Additionally simply calling `{{ dump() }}` inside a document template probably leads to an infinite loading or out of memory errors, because twig tries to dump to much data.

For document templates, the main variable you have access to is the `order`, which is an [OrderEntity](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Checkout/Order/OrderEntity.php). The order entity has a `orderCustomer` property, so you could use a `{{ dump(order.orderCustomer) }}` to get the available data of the customer of an order.

Comment: thank you so much, this answer solved my problem!

Answer (score -1):

To get all available variables in twig use `{{ dump(_context) }}`.